# foreach select not set correctly default option

Tags: php, html, json, laravel, select

I want to loop a  with 12 options. For each option I want to **check** if it is equal to a specific variable in my json.

**When one of the option is equal for 'horaInicio' I have to set that option by default value.**

I have a custom object in my laravel project so I have a json instead an object (I'm using code from another project that is an API that return a json).

Thi is the part of code in my blade view

```
<div class="wrapper_indent">
    @foreach($dias as $dia)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">{{$dia['nombre'] }}</div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">Primer turno</li>
                <select name="example" > 
                    @foreach($dia['horarios'] as $horario)
                        <option {{ ($dia['horaInicio']===$horario)?'selected="selected"':''}} value="{{$dia['horaInicio']}}">{{$horario}}</option> 
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <li class="list-group-item">Último turno</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endforeach

</div><!-- End wrapper_indent -->
```

For more information I enclose the structure of the json
[image]

What's the problem with my select with multiples options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are checking against the wrong property.

In your sample of data `$dia['horaInicio']` would equal `'HIL`, which obviously never matches any of the hours.

I think you need to compare with `$dia['valorInicio']` instead:

```
$dia['valorInicio']===$horario
```

Comment: Haha, you are right. The problem when you pass hours trying to find the error and is so simple that you can't see it